# Bit data type in Java

Tags: java, c, struct, bit

I am writing a program, in Java, which need bit processing, and manipulations. But I could not find any "bit" level primitive datatype. Is there any way in Java to define "bit" datatype?
In C/C++, we can tell compiler how many bits to allocate for variables storage as

```
struct bit {
    unsigned int value : 1;   // 1 bit to store value
};
```

How can I do same thing in Java?

Answer (score 5):

[`boolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.5) or `Boolean` with `true` or `false` (or `Boolean.TRUE` / `Boolean.FALSE`). Both of which can be used with autoboxing and unboxing. There is also a [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) for handling a vector of bits.

Comment: It's interesting that Oracle says the size of boolean isn't precisely defined though it is used to store 1 bit of information: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you mean by "bit".

If you want single bits use a `boolean` and `true`/`false`.

If you want multi-bit fields you'll have to use an integer type (`byte`, `short`, `int` or `long`) and do the masking yourself. There's also `BitSet` for an OO implementation, but it's likely to be slower than masking for small (<64 bits) sets, although better for readability.